# Passing variables to template on class creation inside IntelliJ Plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am creating a Java class inside an IntelliJ plugin using:

```
new JavaDirectoryServiceImpl().createClass(directory, className, templateName);
```

I would like to pass parameters that are used within the template. how can i do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new JavaDirectoryServiceImpl()` is absolutely not intended for use by plugin developers. The correct way to create a file from template with parameters is `FileTemplateUtil.createFromTemplate()`.